# FFMPEG screen regarding using gdi is working as expected when given offset, width and height on different screen size?

Tags: c#, winforms, ffmpeg

I am working on an application that records the screen using ffmpeg. The recording works fine when I don't specify offset, width and height.
When I specify the offset, width and height on my device and records according to the area but when I run it on a big screen and it records smaller area than provided. I am using following command to record:

```
ffmpeg -f gdigrab -framerate " + Framerate + " -offset_x " + OffsetX + " -offset_y " + OffsetY + " -video_size " + width + "x" + height + " -show_region 0 -i desktop " + FileName;
```

I think ffmpeg don't take screen resolution into account or something ?

Comment: is this part of a C# application?

Comment: yes I am starting ffmpeg process with arguments using C#

Comment: Even though it shows the region to be recorded as correct when I put "-show_region 1" in argument

Comment: Is the new device HiDPI?

Comment: yes and its resolution is 1920x1080

Comment: It works fine when I change my resolution to 1280x720

Comment: Finally I solved the my issue after discovering that FFMPEG don't take scaling factor from system and what ever we pass it consider as scaling factor 1 thats the reason it was working fine with my default resolution. 
I got the DpiX and DpiY from system and then the scaling factor. Then I multiplied the points with scaling factor and passed to ffmpeg.
It worked like a charm.
 but don't forget to change compatibility setting of ffmpeg by: right click ffmpeg->properties->compatibility and then check "Disable display scaling on high DPI setting